# How i can NOT handle the selectionchange event in Panoramic View in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

i have developed my own map control (similar Bing Maps control), but when i move this map to right or left, Panorama changes view, but when i move the same bing map, view doesn't change. How i can do the behaviour of my control similarly as in Bing maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your control is trying to handle gestures and so is the Panorama. This was a big issue for a lot of people in the early version of the tools. The standard response was always to avoid this situation as it has implications for usability. Unfortunately there are some situations where you really need this.
The NoDo update (March 2011) included a "fix" to work around this issue for the built in controls. That doesn't help you though.

Fortunately there is a work around.
When contact is made with your control you disable the "IsHitTestVisible" property on the container so that it doesn't also receive the gestures you are capturing. Be sure to set it abck afterwards though.

See http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111 for more details.